# Is it Impossible to Write Hebrew Documents with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, fontspec, polyglossia, linux, hebrew

I'm having a great trouble using a multi-language packages like `polyglossia`/`babel` with `hyperref`.

#### 1<sup>st</sup> trial: `babel`

When I learned to use `babel` with Hebrew I came across the problem described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313950/using-hyperref-in-lyx-pdflatex-hebrew) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32466/hyperref-links-break-with-pdftex-babel-hebrew-or-right-to-left-language) which made me realize that it is currently impossible to use babel in-order to write multi-language bidirectional documents with `hyperref`.

#### 2<sup>nd</sup> and current trial: `polyglossia`

While trying to use `polyglossia` for my documents, I came across weird problems regarding font configuration I still can't fully solve. **And this is the part I'm mostly unsure of**:

### Setup

I use archlinux with with the following `texlive` packages:

```
$ pacman -Qsq texlive
texlive-bibtexextra
texlive-bin
texlive-core
texlive-culmus
texlive-fontsextra
texlive-formatsextra
texlive-humanities
texlive-langextra
texlive-latexextra
texlive-music
texlive-pictures
```

I use `xelatex` in order to produce the documents because `pdflatex` and `lualatex` works with `polyglossia`.

### Example

In the following document, I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible without using unnecessary packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

% General
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\title{הספר שלי}
\author{דורון בכר}
\maketitle
שלום רב,\\
קוראים לי דורון.
% The following 2 lines demonstrate the problem fairly:
% -----------------------------------------------------
%\textenglish{This is a sentence with a url inside it: \url{https://github.com/doronbehar} and it causes problems}
%\textenglish{This is a sentence without a url and it doesn't make problems if all of the document doesn't use hyperref}

\end{document}
```

### Problem

If you uncomment the last sentence (right above `end{document}`) There is no problem when compiling. I don't get any font errors and I can see all characters in the output document. **But**, if I try to uncomment the sentence with the URL as well, I get the following warnings and errors:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `Hebrew'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on input line 21.
```

After a few packages loaded, I get:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmtt.fd)

! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.32 ...de it: \url{https://github.com/doronbehar}
```

I can't getrid of the warning at the begining and the error as well.

### Note:

I've seen a live and working example of using both of these packages from `overleaf.com` [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/chicago-style-polyglossia-xelatex-hebrew-slash-english/rzxytpdsmmvq#.WLNIQO6xXqB). But the writer doesn't use there actual hyperlinks nor urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is imho a bug in the language processing of polyglossia, but harmless.

The error is due to the fact that \url's are written with a typewriter font. polyglossia doesn't handle this correctly: despite that you are in english context it tests if the typewriter font is usable for hebrew. You can find quite a number of questions regarding the "current roman font" problem. The easiest to get around it is to use fonts which have the script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}


\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans}%<--

\begin{document}

\textenglish{This is a sentence with a url inside it: \texttt{blub} and it causes problems}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell it what to use for sans and monowidth fonts in Hebrew, even though the URL is typeset in an English context. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}
% load last unless you know something needs to be loaded later
\usepackage{hyperref}
% bidi needs to be loaded later
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
% US English
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{DejaVu Sans}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{DejaVu Sans}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt{DejaVu Sans}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}


\title{הספר שלי}
\author{דורון בכר}
\maketitle
שלום רב,

קוראים לי דורון.

\textenglish{This is a sentence with a url inside it: \url{https://github.com/doronbehar} and it causes problems}
\textenglish{This is a sentence without a url and it doesn't make problems if all of the document doesn't use hyperref}

\end{document}
```

However, I'm not convinced that it uses the fonts I would expect in this case:

[image: active url]